# How do I upload Bootstrap with cpanel?

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, cpanel

I'm building a website with Bootstrap and while I don't finish I want to upload a template made with Bootstrap. The problem is I host three websites in the host and when I upload the bootstrap file it does not appear. Instead what I got is the follow message: "Error establishing a database connection". I think is because I delete Wordpress from the MySQL. 
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: Put the MySQL database back where it's supposed to be, or remove WordPress. This has little to do with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If your web said

> Error establishing a database connection

, it's a problem at the database, not at bootstrap. Check your file connection, usually `base_url()` need set first.

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap cdn instead. include these in your code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's not going to fix OP's missing MySQL database.